# New to Ajax programming and need some help

Tags: ajax

I was told that AJAX would be the best toolbox to use for building the type of application I am interested in creating.

That being the case, I fired up an old copy of Dreamweaver MX2004 I have and started creating the *.htm, *.js and *.php files. However, when I loaded these files onto my server, I was unable to get the program to do anything. I tried to view the program in IE8, if this explains anything.

Where am I screwing up? Do I need to set a certain flag on my bowser?

I look forward to you response.

Comment: this is a strange question, i have no clue what you are trying to say here, but i get the idea you have no knowledge of JavaScript.
AJAX is no toolbox, it's just a request method, you better start of with a framework like jQuery (check out $.ajax() function).

Answer (score 0):

Does your server have PHP support? What does "unable to get the program to do anything" actually mean? Are you getting error messages? Unexpected results?